# Most efficient way to package php API

Tags: php

I am writing a small api that will involve a number of "commands" with common elements, which involve reading parameters POST'ed to the script(s) and acted upon accordingly

I would like to have the most optimum execution, and am not sure if it's better to have one largish script that switches on a $cmd variable, or to have each command in it's own script.

it all really depends on how php handles script execution. if for example, the script is parsed and tokenized each time on the fly, it would be better to have a lot of short scripts that don't have redundant code being loaded and parsed/tokenized each time.

if however php reads,parses and tokenizes the scripts, and caches the "instructions" in memory, only re-loading/parsing/tokenizeing when the script has actually been edited (eg based on filedate), it would be better to have it all in one script, as then the code could be factorized into functions, and would be easier to maintain, as there would be no repeated code. i don't like the idea of including common files, if that inclusion invokes a reparse each time.

hopefully this question is not to generic in nature - i see no need to give sample code as i am really just wanting to know the best way to "package" my api

Comment: This sounds like a case of *really* premature optimization. Give your API a proper structure (ie. split it into sensible classes and each class into a file; consider using autoloading to include them). That works for every big project out there and if you really need to optimize one day, you can look at things like bytecode caching.

Comment: Optimize your setup first: I guess you don't use the latest php executable and do you use bytecode cache (apc)? Use caching and (if possible) a reverse proxy cache. Regarding parsing: There is _abslutely_ no difference in parsing time, wether the same statements are in one, or in many files. They are the same statements and therefore are parsed the same way.

Comment: If you really need to worry about this, look at APC or something similar.  Once you're using something like that, it doesn't matter -- the parsed code will be cached, so you cut parse time out almost entirely.

Comment: Pekka - i should have explained. i have already coded the api in one script with switch statements. i just looking at the size of the script and realize the question needed to be asked - is it better split it up, or continue as i have been. and i don't buy into objectifying code for the sake of it - sometimes it's more efficient to not go crazy with classes. i want my code to primarily execute fast, and not win awards from warm fuzzy oop lecturers

Comment: @unsynchronized: It's not about objectification here.  It's about modularity.  If you feel like it, just group them up into functions that deal with specific aspects.  They don't *have* to be classes (although if you *make* them classes, it's a lot easier to load only what you're likely to use, thanks to autoloading and such).

Comment: thanks for all your comments. i am relatively new to php, and will take it on board.

Comment: @unsynchronized: The #1 rule to learn about development in general:  *Optimize where it matters.*  As for most scripting languages (including PHP), parse time is generally not a noteworthy part of the problem; if you find it is, you're already doing something else wrong and/or need to look at caching.  Breaking up the files or consolidating them or whatever, can really only do so much by itself.

Comment: in my experience, it almost always matters.

Comment: But it doesn't here. Have you ever benchmarked the overhead you get from including a couple of files? It is almost undetectable. Splitting stuff into classes is perfect for autoloading, it might be worth a try... but there's nothing wrong with including a couple of libraries, either.